# Is there a module to share selected text for Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Medium has a useful feature where any text that you select can be shared via social media. Is there a module for Drupal 8 that works the same way?

[image: Share selected text]

I've found this [Share Selection module](https://www.drupal.org/project/share_selection), but it's not compatible with Drupal 8. And Google has come up empty after a lot of searching. Any help from Drupal veterans is appreciated.

Comment: Did you not check the issue queue? https://www.drupal.org/node/2879693

Comment: My knowledge of Drupal is very limited. I'm looking for something I can install and configure through the admin dashboard.